# Validation Rule Problem - making record read only

Tags: validation-rule

I have the following validation rule:

```
AND(   
$Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',  
OR(  
ISPICKVAL(CustomerRun__c, "Class 1"),  
ISPICKVAL(CustomerRun__c, "Class 2")  
)  
)
```

Basically what I want to do is to make the Record read only (except for System Admin) when `CustomerRun__c` is either set to `Class 1` or to `Class 2`.

I can't see what's wrong with my validation rule.
Tia, Lily

Comment: It is working fine. what issue are you seeing ?

Comment: The issue is when I want to set CustomerRun__c from Class 3 to Class 2, the validation rule triggers, which it shouldn't.

Comment: @Lily ten what you want ?

Comment: When Class 1 or Class 2 are selected, I want the validation rule to trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
AND( 
$Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator', 
OR( 
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(CustomerRun__c), "Class 1"), 
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(CustomerRun__c), "Class 2") 
) 
)
```

your validation rule is preventing Record to be saved with those values, but you need to prevent it from moving away from them.

EDIT
changed rule a little, now should be fine. tested, it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
If( TEXT(CustomerRun__c) =='Class 1' || TEXT(CustomerRun__c) =='Class 2',$Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',false)
```